# Laravel 5.1 - checking if old('varName') is empty - php storm error - arbitrary

Tags: phpstorm, laravel-5.1

I'm using **old('varName')** method to get the previous values of my fields in my view page, and PHPStorm is saying that there's an error in my code but when I run it, it's doing the right thing. Please see image below, **is there something I need to worry about this?**

[image]

The logic behind my code is if old('varName') is not empty, use the current data in the database, else use the old('varName') value.

code:

```
{{    empty(Input::old('businessname')) ? $result['0']->lastname : old('businessname') }}
```

I'm using php 5.5.12

Comment: I guess I have to check how the old() method is being read by phpstorm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you did not setup the php language level in phpstorm correctly.

Go to settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP and set the language level to php 5.5.

[image]